# Moving rows in sqlite database

Tags: qt, sqlite

I have a table that is actually a ranking list. I want to give user a chance to rearrange that top the way he wants, ergo, allow him to move the rows in that table. Should I create a separate column that would hold the place, or can it be done using embedded order in table?

Comment: add the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.

(This is true for all SQL databases.)

So you cannot rely on the order that the rows happen to be stored in; you have to use some value in some table column.